# custom sorting in solr taking into account the value from two fields

Tags: solr

I have a requirement where I have a custom sort function that takes in two fields and a sort order. The sorting should be done based on the lowest value out of the two fields.

Suppose, sort="customsort(field1, field2) asc" will sort documents based on the lowest value selected from two fields for each document.
It is possible that for some documents field1 may have lowest value and for some, field2 may have the lowest value.
example, document1:field1 = 10, field2 = 4 document2:field1 = 5, field2 = 12 document3:field1 = 13, field2 = 2

now after sorting, document3 (lowest value: 2), document1 (lowest value: 4) and document2 (lowest value: 5) should come.

I have looked for value sources supporting this requirement. I know that ValueSource.getSortField() returns SortField object that is used for sorting the documents and SortField can be created for one field.

Comment: `sort=min(field1, field2)` ? Solr can use any function in its sort: https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/function-queries.html#min-function - If you want to speed it up, make the transformation at index time (i.e. index a separate field named `sort_min_value_field1_field2` and submit the lowest value for that field, then sort by that).

Comment: Thanks MatsLindh, I suppose min() works for numeric fields. I have a custom comparator in place that I use for multivalued fields. I am looking for a way where I can return the SortField object from within my custom ValueSource based on the values of the fields. 

adding a new field works but I want to avoid adding a new field